# How can I ensure ingress controller pods are running on each of the nodes that contain the pods for it's backend services?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've setup the [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) Helm chart to setup ingress controllers on my cluster, however by default it only runs a single pod instance.

Since we're running on Digital Ocean's k8s cluster, we're running with `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` to allow cert-manager to access other pods internally, and also so we have less network hops for requests.

For resilience we've configured our backend services to run on at least 2 nodes, so it makes sense that we have ingress controllers on each of the nodes that have a backend pod running on it, to avoid unnecessary inter-node traffic.

How would we go about configuring the ingress controller setup to ensure that we have a controller pod on each of the nodes that the backend pods are running on?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the POD on each node you can use the **daemonset**.

Deamon set : https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/helm-chart/templates/controller-daemonset.yaml

now if you want to make sure Nginx ingress controller POD only run on Nodes on which your backend service running, you can use affinity and anti-affinity.

Affinity example :

```
affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: role
              operator: In
              values:
              - app-1
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: component
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx-ms
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/1-hostname"
```

You can read more and find example at : https://github.com/infracloudio/kubernetes-scheduling-examples/blob/master/podAffinity/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the reference link.  That makes some sense, but I'm unclear whether I should use a DaemonSet if I don't necessarily want them on all nodes.  If I want 'at least 2' pairs of nginx/php pods on a 3 node cluster, is this still a DaemonSet with affinity rules?

Comment: No in that case I would suggest using deployment with affinity and it will work.